# Java Thread Class : java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

This is my first post so sorry if I do something wrong.
I'm trying to understand how work the threads in Java, in particular the synchronization, that's why I created a little piece of code which is supposed to print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (in one thread) and then a second thread wait that's the first finished and then print 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 but it only do the first 6 steps and tell me that there is a monitor problem for the wait method in the thread t2 and a problem with the notify all of the thread t1. Maybe I haven't understood anything about the synchronization of an object. Here is my code :

```
public class anObject extends Thread {

long value;
String name;

public anObject(long value, String name) {
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
}

public synchronized void add() {
    this.value++;
}

public synchronized void sub() {
    this.value--;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    anObject il = new anObject(0, "Bob");

    synchronized (il) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(il) {
            public void run() {
                while (il.value > 0) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    il.add();
                    System.out.println(il.value);
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                il.notifyAll();
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread(il) {
            public void run() {
                while (il.value < 6) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    il.sub();
                    System.out.println(il.value);
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                il.notifyAll();
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

}

And this is what appeared in the terminal :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" 1
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
at anObject$2.run(anObject.java:53)
2
3
4
5
6
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
at anObject$1.run(anObject.java:45)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**wait** is defined in **Object**, this is why you get this exceptions.

I prefer dedicated **lock** for avoid the unpredictable monitor exceptions:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();


private static final class Lock { }
private final Object lock = new Lock();
```

For notify or notifyAll an object, you need to be holding the lock with the synchronized statement. Also, you should define a loop to check for the wakeup condition.

```
synchronized (lock) {
    while (!isWakeupNeeded()) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}
```

To notify:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    makeWakeupNeeded();
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: So you suggest that I create an instance of Object named lock and I synchronized it in my thread instead of synchronize the this Object ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing by this

```
synchronized (il)
```

is just grabbing an object's monitor from the main thread. But inside you are initializing two new threads and trying to call the `wait()` method from the contexts of both of these recently initialized and then started threads. The main idea of IllegalMonitorStateException is that you are trying to call a method that uses a context of object's locking without preceding **obtaining** of this object's lock. What you can do to fix it fast is just to change

```
while (il.value > 0) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

on

```
while (il.value > 0) {
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        this.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and to make an equal change in the second block of code. But to really make it right, I would recommend you to turn to some **strong sources** describing multithreading concept. Oracle's basic java tutorial will be just fine I suppose.

Comment: Okay thank you ! And I will have a look to the tutorial.